# bigquery: count on union of subqueries

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables (`light` and `enhanced`) with slightly different schemas. Second table (`enhanced`) has additional nullable field `t`. 
I want to get count of rows from first and second table per groups based on two fields (`d,p`)

To achieve this I'm using union of subqueries with asterisk

```
select
  d
  , p
  ,count(1) - count(t) light_cnt
  ,count(t) enhanced_cnt
from 
  (select * from light)
  , (select * from enhanced)
group by
  d, p
```

But this query returns wrong counts (something about twice as much)
This is only happening when I group by two fields. Single field works well. I found out that it works correctly when I wrap union in another subquery

```
select
  d
  , p
  ,count(1) - count(t) light_cnt
  ,count(t) enhanced_cnt
from
  (select * from 
      (select * from light)
      , (select * from enhanced)
  )
group by
  d, p
```

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

---

### EDIT:

I have reproduced same corrupted behaviour without `group by`, just with `where`

```
select count(1) from enhanced where p = 124
```

returns 292

```
select count(1) from light where p = 124
```

returns 12512

```
select count(1)
from (select * from light), (select * from enhanced)
where p = 124
```

returns 12804 which is correct, while

```
select count(1), count(t)
from (select * from light), (select * from enhanced)
where p = 124
```

returns 24527, 501... very strange. Seems to be a bug.

Workaround:

```
select count(1), count(t)
from (select * from (select * from light), (select * from enhanced))
where p = 124
```

returns 12804, 292. Correct.

Both tables `light` and `enhanced` have complicated schemas inherited from avro. There are records and repeated fields. Field `p` and `t` are in abbverviated form in select above for sake of simplicity. Real is `p -> record.record.record.id` (leaf is integer), and `t -> record.time` (leaf is integer). None of records in path `p` nor `t` are repeatable. All are nullable.

Comment: Just trying to debug this. Is there a difference beteen the counts if you only do select count(*) in both?

Comment: What's the structure of the tables? Any repeated/nested structures?

Comment: @sjuul simple counts of this two tables:
 `select count(*) from light` returns 50607517, and 233162 for `enhanced`. 

While `select
  sum(light_cnt)
  ,sum(enhanced_cnt)
from([first query])` returns 105536984 and 639161. Sums selected from second query are correct.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa yes, both tables have nested and repeated structures. Type of column `d` is derived from integer seconds to timestamp, `p` is nested `record.record.record.id` integer , and `t` is also nested `record.time` integer

Answer (score 2):

See [Difference in statistics from Google Analytics Report and BigQuery Data in Hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821865/difference-in-statistics-from-google-analytics-report-and-bigquery-data-in-hive), you are probably having similar issues as you are flattening data from 2 repeated columns: That produces n*m results.

A query that demonstrates this:

```
SELECT col, x FROM (
  SELECT "wrong" col, SUM(totals.pageviews) x
  FROM (FLATTEN ([google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910], hits))
), (
  SELECT "correct" col, SUM(totals.pageviews) x
  FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]
)

col     x    
wrong   2262     
correct 249
```

A query that shows exactly what you are experiencing. All the resulting numbers should be the same, but they are not - the result depends on the FLATTEN() choices that BigQuery makes. If you want to get the right numbers, be explicit about how BigQuery should flatten the table before counting:

```
SELECT a, b, c    FROM (
SELECT COUNT(1)  a
FROM (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ), (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] )
),(
SELECT COUNT(customDimensions.index) b
FROM (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ), (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] )
),(
SELECT COUNT(hits.hitNumber) c
FROM (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ), (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] )
),(
SELECT COUNT(1)  a, COUNT(customDimensions.index) b, COUNT(hits.hitNumber) c
FROM (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ), (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] )
),(
SELECT COUNT(1)  a, COUNT(customDimensions.index) b
FROM (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ), (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] )
),(
SELECT COUNT(1)  a, COUNT(hits.hitNumber) c
FROM (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ), (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] )
),(
SELECT COUNT(customDimensions.index) b, COUNT(hits.hitNumber) c
FROM (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ), (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] )
),(
SELECT COUNT(1) a, COUNT(customDimensions.index) b, COUNT(hits.hitNumber) c
FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910], [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910])

Row a   b   c    
1   126          
2       510      
3           724  
4   126 102 766  
5   726 510      
6   126     724  
7       102 766  
8   126 102 724
```

Comment: Thanks @Felipe, this is somehow helpful, but I still do not understand how my workaround works. Is wrapping union of subqueries in another subquery (one level higher) works as saying to bigquery "do not flatten at all"? I mean why `SELECT count(1) a, COUNT(customDimensions.index) b, COUNT(hits.hitNumber) c
FROM (Select * from (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ), (SELECT * FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ))` works correct?

Comment: By simple observation, yes. But why not chose the simple version without so many stars: `SELECT COUNT(1) a, COUNT(customDimensions.index) b, COUNT(hits.hitNumber) c
FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910], [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]`

Comment: ok, in this example is sufficient, but I have two tables with slightly **different** schema so union of subqueries with stars unifies them. This is a must I think.